# How to get feature_column value given raw features outside of Estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In all the examples for using the `feature_column` API in `Tensorflow`, they show how to create your raw features in the `input_fn` and then a `feature_column` array defining the desired mappings, which are then both passed to an `Estimator`. During runtime, the `Estimator` then combines the two behind the scenes and does the actual feature encoding. How can I do this outside of the `Estimator` API? I already looked through the source code of `Tensorflow` and came up empty handed.

Here is some source code that could be used to demonstrate what I need. I would like to create a combined feature of age using `age-buckets` and `education` resulting in `[2,0]`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

feature_names = [
    'age','education']

label_names = [
'>50K',
'<=50K']

d = dict(zip(feature_names, [34, 'Bachelors'])), '>50K'

print(d)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    age = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('age')
    age_buckets = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(age, boundaries=[18, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65])    
    education = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    'education', [
        'Bachelors', 'HS-grad', '11th', 'Masters', '9th', 'Some-college',
        'Assoc-acdm', 'Assoc-voc', '7th-8th', 'Doctorate', 'Prof-school',
        '5th-6th', '10th', '1st-4th', 'Preschool', '12th'])
    base_columns = [age_buckets, education]
    print(base_columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you just need to use `tf.feature_column.input_layer` in addition to `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession()`, which initializes the required tables.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

feature_names = [
    'age','education']

d = dict(zip(feature_names, [[34], ['Bachelors']])), '>50K'

print(d[0])
age = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('age')
age_buckets = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(age, boundaries=[18, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65]) 
education_vocabulary_list = [
    'Bachelors', 'HS-grad', '11th', 'Masters', '9th', 'Some-college',
    'Assoc-acdm', 'Assoc-voc', '7th-8th', 'Doctorate', 'Prof-school',
    '5th-6th', '10th', '1st-4th', 'Preschool', '12th'] 
education = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('education', vocabulary_list=education_vocabulary_list)
eductation_indicator = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(education)
feature_columns = [age_buckets, eductation_indicator]
print(feature_columns)

input_layer = tf.feature_column.input_layer(
    features=d[0],
    feature_columns=feature_columns
)

zero = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
where = tf.not_equal(input_layer, zero)
indices = tf.where(where)
values = tf.gather_nd(input_layer, indices)
sparse = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, input_layer.shape)


with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession() as sess:

    print(input_layer)
    print(sess.run(input_layer))
    print(sess.run(sparse))
```

Comment: the above code runs fine but as per the documentation here (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/indicator_column) usage of indicator_column should give multi-hot representation but in the above i see two sparse tensors corresponding to each output. What is I have a categorical variable that has two fields in the education field like [Bachelors  HS-grad] . How do I get the multi hot representation ? My input field is supposed to be space separated. @herrtim